# What am I doing wrong with this phone SESSION I'm trying to print to screen?

Tags: php, session, post, session-variables

I am testing a SESSION where the three prior pages prints to the last page. But I'm have trouble getting it to work. Everything goes well until the last page. Here is the code:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST ['name'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST ['email'];
$_SESSION['age'] = $_POST ['age'];

echo $_SESSION['name'];
echo $_SESSION['email'];
echo $_SESSION['age'];
}
?>
```

I'm getting a blank or a index error for the session variable. Can anyone help with the correct way to print user inputted session data?

These are the 1st, 2nd and 3rd pages:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>phpsession</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="test_2_page_1.php">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="enter name"></input>
<input type="submit"> next</input>
</form>
<?php
//Set session variables
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST ['name'];
}
?>
</body>
</html>


<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST ['name'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST ['email'];
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>phpsession</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="test_2_page_2.php">
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="enter email"></input>
<input type="submit"> next</input>
</form>
<?php
// Set session variables
?>
</body>
</html>


<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST ['name'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST ['email'];
$_SESSION['age'] = $_POST ['age'];
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>phpsession</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="post_test.php">
<input type="text" name="age" placeholder="enter age"></input>
<input type="submit"> next</input>
</form>
<?php
// Set session variables
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share what the form you are posting looks like?

Comment: I have just updated the original post.

Comment: You have some invalid HTML tag. You never go inside your condition in `test_2_page_2.php` you need to replace `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { ` to `if (!empty($_POST)){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `input` element is `self-closing` in that you do not need `</input>` - rather the tag is simply closed using `/>`

To display `Next` as the submit button you would use the value attribute - ie: `<input type='submit' value='Next' />`

Once the session variable is assigned you do not need to keep trying to set it and will encounter errors if the variable is not available in the POST array - so use `isset` to test prior to creating a variable

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if ( isset( $_POST['submit'], $_POST['name'] ) ) { 
        $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
    }   
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>phpsession</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="test_2_page_1.php">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="enter name" />
            <input type="submit" name='submit' value='Next'>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>





<?php
    session_start();
    if ( isset( $_POST['submit'], $_POST['email'] ) ) {
        $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>phpsession</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="test_2_page_2.php">
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="enter email" />
            <input type="submit" name='submit' value='Next'>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>







<?php
    session_start();
    if( isset( $_POST['submit'],$_POST['age'] ) ) {
        $_SESSION['age'] = $_POST['age'];
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>phpsession</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="post_test.php">
            <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="enter age" />
            <input type="submit" name='submit' value='Next'>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

To further help you solve your issues I quickly put together a single page demo of getting and setting the session variables based upon form submissions.. hope it'll help

```
<?php
    session_start();
    #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54194496/what-am-i-doing-wrong-with-this-phone-session-im-trying-to-print-to-screen/54194890?noredirect=1#comment95217192_54194890

    if( !empty( $_GET['reset'] ) ){
        unset( $_SESSION['name'] );
        unset( $_SESSION['email'] );
        unset( $_SESSION['age'] );
        header( sprintf('Location: %s', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] ) );
    }

    /* 
        as each form only submits two values ( submit being one ) we can
        simply remove it from the POST array and use the remaining field/value
        to generate the session variables using simple array techniques

        The below could easily be replaced with pre-defined variables, such as:
        if( isset( $_POST['name'] ) )$_SESSION['name']=$_POST['name']; etc

    */
    if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
        /* remove the submit button & value from the array */
        unset( $_POST['submit'] );

        /* there will now be one item, with index = 0 */
        $keys=array_keys( $_POST );
        $values=array_values( $_POST );

        /* set the session variable */
        $_SESSION[ $keys[0] ]=$values[0];
    }

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>phpsession</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='POST'>
        <?php
            if( empty( $_SESSION['name'] ) ){
                echo "<input type='text' name='name' placeholder='enter name' />";
            }
            if( !empty( $_SESSION['name'] ) && empty( $_SESSION['email'] ) ){
                echo "<input type='text' name='email' placeholder='enter email address' />";
            }
            if( !empty( $_SESSION['name'] ) && !empty( $_SESSION['email'] ) && empty( $_SESSION['age'] ) ){
                echo "<input type='text' name='age' placeholder='enter your age' />";
            }
            if( empty( $_SESSION['age'] ) ){
                echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Next'>";
            } else {
                if( empty( $_POST['finish'] ) ) echo "<input type='submit' name='finish' value='Finish'>";
            }
            if( isset( $_POST['finish'] ) ){
                /* 
                    Once the user has completed each form, send them off to their final destination?
                    or do something else....
                */
                printf(
                    'Do some interesting stuff now ....
                    <pre>%s</pre><a href="?reset=true">Reset</a>',
                    print_r( $_SESSION, true )
                );
            }
        ?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what didn't work? In the above html snippets are the form actions the same page?

Comment: No it progress across 3 pages. Last should post but doesn't. On est time feeling sleepy. Been up all night trying to get this thing to work. If I don't respond I will first thing in the morning.

Comment: I ran the above code until the last page I'm still stuck with nothing or undefined variable errors.

Comment: ? really ? I just re-ran the above and I don't get any errors, please tell me what the messages are

Comment: Notice: Undefined index:

Comment: I tried to use the print method instead to display all in the session data. After plugging in the last code exactly how you have I finally have some results. I'm going to read through in thoroughly to try to figure how you use the language and what I did wrong and how I can use session better in the future. I appreciate your time in showing me how to solve my problem.

Comment: good luck...I used `printf` just for convenience really, it is not essential by any means. The important thing to remember is to test for the existence of the variable in the POSTed array data before attempting to set as a session variable

Comment: One more quick question is it possible to do what was done with the code you posted with 4 pages instead of one? If so how? And  what would be better as in more responsive? My actual project has bootstrap and css design implemented already. Would it be best to convert to one page or convert the session code to correlate to the 4 pages I already have for the front end?

Comment: yes, it's possible to do this with 4 pages and you would do it rather like you tried initially and either set the form action to the same page as the form and then use `header(location:blah)` to progress to next page or set the form action to the next page. IMO it is easier to maintain one page rather than 4.. I can't answer "would it be best to..." as it is personal preferences

Comment: Thank you so much! You gave me a week of my life back! Wish I could help you in return. Thank you.

Comment: I just put together a multi-page demo for you if you want to examine it... it's hosted on `wetransfer.com` for 7days

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/d28933c379e0092bef20e24e425fbf0f20190118164717/c698f7bca3f120c84fcc7323f49054dc20190118164717/5cf4b1

Comment: This is great. I'm a bit confused by the language but this is very similar to what I want. Thanks for a great building block.

Answer (score 0):

You have no input element in your HTML with the name `submit` so the following part of your PHP code will always evaluate to `false`:

`if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {`

Change the submit button in your HTML to the following and the line above will evaluate to `true` when the form is posted:

`<input name="submit" type="submit"> next</input>`

Comment: Please explain like I'm five

Comment: PS that didn't work. I ended up with even more errors.